# Wildfly 8, mod_cluster & apache integration

Tags: apache, jboss, wildfly, mod-cluster

I am having problems getting mod_cluster 1.2 to work with Apache. I want the configuration to allow Apache to proxy my traffic to the apps server so that myserver.com:9191 (apache) routes traffic to myserver.com:9090 (jboss)

**Symptoms:**

When I start Wildfly the console produces the following error every 3-5 seconds:

ERROR [org.jboss.modcluster] (UndertowEventHandlerAdapter - 1) MODCLUSTER000042: Error null sending INFO command to precise32/127.0.1.1:6666, configuration will be reset: null

I can see a corresponding request in my Apache logs as: "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

The myserver:9191/mod_cluster-manager URL only shows the page title and links, but no cluster info, like this:
***mod_cluster/1.2.6.Final***

*Auto Refresh show DUMP output show INFO output*

I am running both jboss and apache on the same virtual server.

**Server Info:**

Virtual Box 4.3.14 running:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Apache/2.2.22

Wildfly 8.0

I can navigate to my web apps on Wildfly directly without going through Apache and it works fine. If I try and navigate through Apache, I get the following errors in my Apache log:

[Thu Oct 16 03:12:33 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(2231): proxy: byrequests balancer FAILED

[Thu Oct 16 03:12:33 2014] [error] proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://mycluster). All workers are in error state

[Thu Oct 16 03:12:33 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.0.2.2] Zlib: Compressed 410 to 276 : URL /

**My relevant Apache configs look like:**

**mod_cluster.load:**

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
```

LoadModule advertise_module     /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_advertise.so

LoadModule manager_module               /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_manager.so

LoadModule proxy_cluster_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so

LoadModule slotmem_module               /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_slotmem.so

**mod_cluster.conf:**

CreateBalancers 1

```
Listen 127.0.1.1:6666

ManagerBalancerName mycluster



<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1:6666>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300

    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

    AdvertiseFrequency 5

    ServerAdvertise On



    <Location />

        Order deny,allow

        Allow from 127.0.0

    </Location>



 </VirtualHost>
```

**virtual host:**

```
#ServerAdmin me@domain.edu

ServerName jboss.cluster

ServerAlias jboss.cluster


ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location />

    Order deny,allow

    Allow from All

</Location>
```

```
  SetHandler mod_cluster-manager

  Order deny,allow

  #Deny from all

  Allow from 127.0.0
```

```
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jboss_cluster_error.log

    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jboss_access.log combined
```

**standalone.xml:**

```
<extensions>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
<extension module="org.jboss.as.modcluster"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
</extensions>
```

...

```
<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">


<dynamic-load-provider>


<load-metric type="cpu"/>


</dynamic-load-provider>


</mod-cluster-config>


</subsystem>
```

......

```
<interface name="public">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
<interface name="unsecure">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
</interfaces>


<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
<socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:9090}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

vhost error log jboss_cluster_error.log:

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:49 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:11:51 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:13:55 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.0.2.2] Zlib: Compressed 494 to 255 : URL /mod_cluster-manager

[Thu Oct 16 18:13:58 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1010): update_workers_node starting

[Thu Oct 16 18:13:58 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(1025): update_workers_node done

[Thu Oct 16 18:13:59 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.0.2.2] Zlib: Compressed 494 to 255 : URL /mod_cluster-manager

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:05 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(2231): proxy: byrequests balancer FAILED

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:05 2014] [error] proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://mycluster). All workers are in error state

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:05 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.0.2.2] Zlib: Compressed 400 to 269 : URL /

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:13 2014] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(2231): proxy: byrequests balancer FAILED

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:13 2014] [error] proxy: CLUSTER: (balancer://mycluster). All workers are in error state

[Thu Oct 16 18:14:13 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.0.2.2] Zlib: Compressed 400 to 269 : URL /

vhost access log jboss_access.log

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:11:49 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"

10.0.2.2 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:13:55 +0000] "GET /mod_cluster-manager HTTP/1.1" 200 556 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

10.0.2.2 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:13:59 +0000] "GET /mod_cluster-manager HTTP/1.1" 200 529 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

10.0.2.2 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

10.0.2.2 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

vhost access log other_vhosts_access.log

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:13:43 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:13:53 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:03 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:13 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:23 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:33 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:43 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:14:53 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:03 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:13 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:23 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:33 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:43 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:15:53 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:16:03 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:16:13 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

precise32:6666 127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014:18:16:23 +0000] "INFO / HTTP/1.1" 501 529 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0"

Message was edited by: M P Added in complete apache error and access logs. Also added in my ProxyPass config to the vhost.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my configuration working. The problem was with my mod_cluster.conf file. I was missing the 2 directives:

```
    ServerAdvertise On 127.0.1.1:6666
    EnableMCPMReceive
```

hope this helps someone...

```
Listen 127.0.1.1:6666

ManagerBalancerName mycluster

<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1:6666>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300

    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0

    AdvertiseFrequency 5

    ServerAdvertise On 127.0.1.1:6666
    EnableMCPMReceive

    <Location />

        Order deny,allow

       # Allow from 127.0.0

       Allow from all

    </Location>

 </VirtualHost>
```